# Pandas return number of vaccination per vaccine group by country

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

```
BestV = vacc2.groupby(["location","vaccine"], as_index=False)[["total_vaccinations"]].count().sort_values(by='total_vaccinations',ascending=False)
BestV.head()
```

I need to group by location with the sum of the total injections per vaccine manufacturer, like:

```
Argentina : Astra   12300
            Moderna 12551
            Pfizer  55200 
            ......
Brazil    : Astra   65412
            Moderna 14526
            Pfizer  14551
```

My dataset is like this:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
BestV = vacc2[['location', 'vaccine', 'total_vaccinations']] \
        .groupby(["location","vaccine"]) \
        .sum() \
        .sort_values(by='total_vaccinations', ascending=False) \
        .reset_index()

BestV.head()
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.

Comment: In not working, there is another way to do this?